# Relation for fields

Tags: 7, entities

The [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module supports creating relations between entities. Is there a way I could create relations between fields.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your needs. Can you elaborate, or perhaps give an example?

Comment: I need to create relations between fields, such that a field has a parent/sibling, and can be in relation to the other fields that have the same parent .. and much more that the relation module exactly provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Relation can only link entities to eachother. Since field values are not entities themselves (they don't even have unique ID's), Relation will probably not be able solve your problem.

Maybe [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) can be useful to you. It's not exactly what you describe, but it's the only module I know that allows you to bundle fields into meaningful groups.

Comment: this was my idea initially, and the only one that feels right in the situation.